# How to get k8s nodes without pods running on it?

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to get k8s nodes without pods running on it from kubectl?
Here we have 3 k8s nodes:
node1
node2
node3
And a pod runnnig on node1.
Can i use kubectl to list node2 and node3?

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: I just want to filter free nodes use kubetl (if possible). for example,there is no pods running on node1 and node2,and pod1 running on node3. can i  use kubectl get nodes  to get all free nodes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to filter the empty nodes

```
kubectl get nodes --no-headers | awk '{print $1}' | grep -v "$(kubectl get pods -o=custom-columns=NAME:.spec.nodeName -n <enter-the-namespace-here> | sort -u)"
```

Remove the `awk` to get detailed info on the nodes.

```
kubectl get nodes --no-headers | grep -v "$(kubectl get pods -o=custom-columns=NAME:.spec.nodeName -n <enter-the-namespace-here> | sort -u)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use this one-line script:

```
comm -23 <(kubectl get nodes --no-headers | awk '{print $1}' | sort) <(kubectl get pods --no-headers -n <name_of_your_namespace_to_search> -owide | awk '{print $7}' | sort)
```

But one nuance, it searches for selected namespace not only for the pod.